# PHP ldap connection always turns out true

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to make an connection with an active directory to authenticate a user.
However it doesnt matter what you type in as it will put you trough either way.

I am not even sure if I make the right connection.
as host name I currently use [ip adress].[domain].nl
and I do not know if this is even possible, but it didn't turn out an error when I checked the ldap_connect() for errors.

so if you guys would like to look over the code and give me tips, that would be great. I left out the connection details for security reasons.

sry if this is a stupid question but I have bo idea on whats wrong.
Thanks in advance.

```
class LOGIN{
        public function login($data){

            $user = $data["username"];
            $password = $data["password"];
            $host = 'ldap://[ip adress]/[domain].nl';
            $domain = '[domain].nl';
            $basedn = 'dc=[domain],dc=nl';

            $ad = ldap_connect($host.$domain,389) or die('Could not connect to LDAP server.');

            ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
            ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

            //$bind = ldap_bind($ad, "$user@$domain", $password) or die('Could not bind to AD.');

            if(@ldap_bind($ad, "$user"."@"."$domain", $password)){

                $result = "Authenticated";

            }else{
                $result = "Invalid Credential";
            }               

            return $result;
        }
    }
}

$login = new LOGIN;
```

And this is the form to log in:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){

require_once("classes/class_login.php");

$result = $login->login($_POST);

}   
?>

<form action="#" method="POST">
    <?php if(!empty($result)){echo "<p>".$result."</p>";} ?>
    <pre>
    <label for="username">Username: </label><input id="username" type="text" name="username" /> 
    <label for="password">Password: </label><input id="password" type="password" name="password" />       

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </pre>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, there is probably something wrong with the api, it always returns true. That's the working implementation that we used.

```
    define('LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE', 0x0032);
    $conn = "ldap://whatever.com";   // 
    $port = "389";        // by default port 389
    $version = "3";       // by default 3
    $referral = "0"; // by default 0
    $user = "username";
    $password = "password";

    if ($user && $password) {
        //Connect LDAP Server
        echo " connecting to ldap mdec<br/> ";
        $connect = ldap_connect($conn, $port);
        ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, $version);
        ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, $referral);

        $bind = ldap_bind($connect, $user, $password);
        if ($bind) {
            echo "OK. ";
        } else {
            echo "couldn't bind.";
            if (ldap_get_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $extended_error)) {
                echo "Error connecting to LDAP: $extended_error";
            } else {
                echo "Error connecting to LDAP: No additional information is available.";
            }
        }
        ldap_close($connect);
    } else {
        echo "in else, do whatever you want to show to the user";
   }
```

Comment: I managed to fix it by looking up the correct DN on CMD. But your answer helped a ton by adding the error messages. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ldap_connect` takes the provided URI and checks it for syntactical correctness. **NO** connection is established to the server!

The actual connection will be created on the first call to the server (which is typically `ldap_bind`) so connection-issues might present themself at the `ldap_bind` command!

Besides that, `ldap_connect` should be called with a single parameter containing an LDAP-URI like `ldap://ldap.example.com:1234` or `ldaps://192.168.1.1:4567`. Stop using it with two parameters `hostname` and `port` as that is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of PHP as there's no way of using it for a secure connection. Always call it like `ldap_connect('ldap://ldap.example.com:1234');`!